# How to build filter class using django-filter that allows to query by multiple values of one model field

Tags: django, django-filter, query-string

I have to build endpoint that must allow to filter by multiple values. It must looks like this:

```
http://example.com/page?field=1&field=2&filed=3
```

Lets say that `field` is an `IntegField` of `MyModel`. An I want to query by any value in this `field`.

I want to execute such or similiar query + validate the list of query params

```
MyModel.objects.filter(field__in=[1,2,3])
```

django-filter(https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library looks promising but in the documentation I have not found an easy way to do something so simple. How can I achieve this?

Validation is also imortant. I dont want to allow to execute query with such param `field=yolo`

So far I have ended up with code that does not support validation

```
import django_filters as df
from django.forms.widgets import SelectMultiple
    

class MyFilter(df.FilterSet):
    id = df.Filter(required=False, field_name="id", widget=SelectMultiple(), lookup_expr="in")

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ["id"]
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at BaseInFilter: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#baseinfilter
It provides an example of creating a NumberInFilter, which would do what you like, but you'd have to sort out the user input.

Comment: @TimNyborg yes, but it only allows to make a query like this http://example.com/page?field=1,2,3 - And I expect this http://example.com/page?field=1&field=2&filed=3
Probably it is possible to override sth like here https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/pull/1340/files but I takes to much effort to do someting so simple

Comment: Ah, I see.  I think you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not the most elegant way, but this is how I achieved the goal:

```
from django_filters.fields import BaseCSVField
from django_filters.widgets import QueryArrayWidget

class MyBaseCSVField(BaseCSVField):
    base_widget_class = QueryArrayWidget


class MyBaseInFilter(df.BaseInFilter):
    base_field_class = MyBaseCSVField


class NumberInFilter(MyBaseInFilter, df.NumberFilter):
    pass


class MytFilter(df.FilterSet):
    field = NumberInFilter()

    class Meta:
        modem = MyModel
        fields = ("field", )
```

So the key here is the `QueryArrayWidget` and from the docstrin:

```
 1. Values can be provided as csv string:  ?foo=bar,baz
 2. Values can be provided as query array: ?foo[]=bar&foo[]=baz
 3. Values can be provided as query array: ?foo=bar&foo=baz
```

Generally this library is not well documented in my honest opinion.